# Making an SVG link to another website

Tags: html, css, svg

I've added some social media svg icons on my page, I've added them this way so I can edit the attributes in the CSS. Is there any way I can make them link to the social media sites, so when a user clicks them it opens in another tab?

```
<ul id="shareMenu">
    <li class="shareLi">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="29" height="29" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path class="webIcon" d="M19 0h-14c-2.761 0-5 2.239-5 5v14c0 2.761 2.239 5 5 5h14c2.762 0 5-2.239 5-5v-14c0-2.761-2.238-5-5-5zm-3 7h-1.924c-.615 0-1.076.252-1.076.889v1.111h3l-.238 3h-2.762v8h-3v-8h-2v-3h2v-1.923c0-2.022 1.064-3.077 3.461-3.077h2.539v3z"/>
        </svg>
    </li>
    <li class="shareLi">
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
         <svg viewbox="0 0 2000 1625.36" width="29" height="29" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
             <path class="twitterIcon" d="m 1999.9999,192.4 c -73.58,32.64 -152.67,54.69 -235.66,64.61 84.7,-50.78 149.77,-131.19 180.41,-227.01 -79.29,47.03 -167.1,81.17 -260.57,99.57 C 1609.3399,49.82 1502.6999,0 1384.6799,0 c -226.6,0 -410.328,183.71 -410.328,410.31 0,32.16 3.628,63.48 10.625,93.51 -341.016,-17.11 -643.368,-180.47 -845.739,-428.72 -35.324,60.6 -55.5583,131.09 -55.5583,206.29 0,142.36 72.4373,267.95 182.5433,341.53 -67.262,-2.13 -130.535,-20.59 -185.8519,-51.32 -0.039,1.71 -0.039,3.42 -0.039,5.16 0,198.803 141.441,364.635 329.145,402.342 -34.426,9.375 -70.676,14.395 -108.098,14.395 -26.441,0 -52.145,-2.578 -77.203,-7.364 52.215,163.008 203.75,281.649 383.304,284.946 -140.429,110.062 -317.351,175.66 -509.5972,175.66 -33.1211,0 -65.7851,-1.949 -97.8828,-5.738 181.586,116.4176 397.27,184.359 628.988,184.359 754.732,0 1167.462,-625.238 1167.462,-1167.47 0,-17.79 -0.41,-35.48 -1.2,-53.08 80.1799,-57.86 149.7399,-130.12 204.7499,-212.41"/>
         </svg>
    </li>
    <li class="shareLi">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="29" height="29" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path class="instaIcon" d="M11.984 16.815c2.596 0 4.706-2.111 4.706-4.707 0-1.409-.623-2.674-1.606-3.538-.346-.303-.735-.556-1.158-.748-.593-.27-1.249-.421-1.941-.421s-1.349.151-1.941.421c-.424.194-.814.447-1.158.749-.985.864-1.608 2.129-1.608 3.538 0 2.595 2.112 4.706 4.706 4.706zm.016-8.184c1.921 0 3.479 1.557 3.479 3.478 0 1.921-1.558 3.479-3.479 3.479s-3.479-1.557-3.479-3.479c0-1.921 1.558-3.478 3.479-3.478zm5.223.369h6.777v10.278c0 2.608-2.114 4.722-4.722 4.722h-14.493c-2.608 0-4.785-2.114-4.785-4.722v-10.278h6.747c-.544.913-.872 1.969-.872 3.109 0 3.374 2.735 6.109 6.109 6.109s6.109-2.735 6.109-6.109c.001-1.14-.327-2.196-.87-3.109zm2.055-9h-12.278v5h-1v-5h-1v5h-1v-4.923c-.346.057-.682.143-1 .27v4.653h-1v-4.102c-1.202.857-2 2.246-2 3.824v3.278h7.473c1.167-1.282 2.798-2 4.511-2 1.722 0 3.351.725 4.511 2h7.505v-3.278c0-2.608-2.114-4.722-4.722-4.722zm2.722 5.265c0 .406-.333.735-.745.735h-2.511c-.411 0-.744-.329-.744-.735v-2.53c0-.406.333-.735.744-.735h2.511c.412 0 .745.329.745.735v2.53z"/>
        </svg>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simply surround them with an `<a>´ https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18732/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="url" target=_blank>SVG</a></li>
</ul>
```

A standard link opening in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an SVG to link to another website, you simply do it exactly the same way you would do it with an image:

```
<a href="http://www.instagram.com/path/to/search/link">
    <img src="myplaceimage.png"></img>
</a>
```

Likewise:

```
<a href="http://www.instagram.com/path/to/search/link">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="29" height="29" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path class="instaIcon" d="M11.984 16.815c2.596 0 4.706-2.111 4.706-4.707 0-1.409-.623-2.674-1.606-3.538-.346-.303-.735-.556-1.158-.748-.593-.27-1.249-.421-1.941-.421s-1.349.151-1.941.421c-.424.194-.814.447-1.158.749-.985.864-1.608 2.129-1.608 3.538 0 2.595 2.112 4.706 4.706 4.706zm.016-8.184c1.921 0 3.479 1.557 3.479 3.478 0 1.921-1.558 3.479-3.479 3.479s-3.479-1.557-3.479-3.479c0-1.921 1.558-3.478 3.479-3.478zm5.223.369h6.777v10.278c0 2.608-2.114 4.722-4.722 4.722h-14.493c-2.608 0-4.785-2.114-4.785-4.722v-10.278h6.747c-.544.913-.872 1.969-.872 3.109 0 3.374 2.735 6.109 6.109 6.109s6.109-2.735 6.109-6.109c.001-1.14-.327-2.196-.87-3.109zm2.055-9h-12.278v5h-1v-5h-1v5h-1v-4.923c-.346.057-.682.143-1 .27v4.653h-1v-4.102c-1.202.857-2 2.246-2 3.824v3.278h7.473c1.167-1.282 2.798-2 4.511-2 1.722 0 3.351.725 4.511 2h7.505v-3.278c0-2.608-2.114-4.722-4.722-4.722zm2.722 5.265c0 .406-.333.735-.745.735h-2.511c-.411 0-.744-.329-.744-.735v-2.53c0-.406.333-.735.744-.735h2.511c.412 0 .745.329.745.735v2.53z"/>
    </svg>
</a>
```